# Present perfect progressive vs Present simple to express repeating action

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense, present-continuous

> I **have usually been flying** northern routes over the poles.
>
> I **have been flying** overseas trips **every  Tuesday and Wednesday**.

There is no other context, it's phrases from a tutorial.

We can say: "I usually fly northern routes over the poles" and "I fly overseas trips every Tuesday and Wednesday", can't we? What's the difference in the meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is very little difference between them; substituting one for the other will not change your meaning appreciably.

We *tend*, however (and it is no more than a tendency), to use the simple present  form when we are speaking of an unchanging routine, and the continuous perfect form when we are speaking of a routine for which we contemplate a beginning or end, or both.

So you're more likely to hear "I usually fly northern routes" than "I have usually been flying ...", because *usually* has a 'built-in' sense of an enduring routine which is only occasionally departed from.

And a pilot assigned to a specific route is more likely to say "I fly overseas trips every Tuesday and Wednesday" if the assignment is more or less permanent, or if the context is her current schedule

> I can't make your party; I fly overseas trips every Tuesday and Wednesday.

while "I have been flying overseas trips every Tuesday and Wednesday" would be said if she is speaking of when this schedule started or of a possible future change in the schedule.

> I have been flying overseas every Tuesday and Wednesday since 2004.
>   I have been flying overseas every Tuesday and Wednesday lately, but I've asked to go back on the Thursday-Friday schedule.